# Infeasible Test Requirments - Testing

Tags: testing

**What will be the maximum possible coverage level of edge pair coverage and what will be the infeasible?** 
with diagram?

```
BEGIN
    input (a)
    if (a<0) then
      a=(-a)
    end if
    if(a>0) then 
      a++
    end if
    print (a)
    END
```